# The resource type could not be found in the namespace Microsoft.storage for api version 2018-01-01- Azure Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-resource-manager

I'm creating a metric alert on Azure storage for that I do have an ARM template
While I execute it through Azure Powershell then I receive an error as mentioned below and I'm not sure what is causing this issue.

POWERSHELL COMMAND : `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -name "StorageBlobDeployment" -ResourceGroupName TestStorage-RG -TemplateFile "C:\ARM\azureDeploy.storage.json" -TemplateParameterFile "C:\ARM\azureDeploy.storage.parameters.json"`

Though it works fine when I deploy same ARM template through Portal.

ERROR below:

```
new-AzResourceGroupDeployment : 2:37:34 PM - Resource microsoft.insights/metricAlerts '-storage_account_ingress_traffic_alert' failed with message '{
  "Code": "BadRequest",
  "Message": "The resource type could not be found in the namespace 'Microsoft.storage' for api version '2018-01-01'."
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've tried updating Az module but no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this is happening because your Azure Powershell is outdated. Update it and it will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've tried updating Az module but no success

Comment: yeah, basically this happens because its using some hardcoded api-version, and it was not new enough to support that feature.